# How to Find All CALayers assoicated with an nsview?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, osx-lion, audiounit

I'm hosting Apple's Pitch Shift Audio Unit plugin in Mac OSX 10.7 Lion. The pitchShiftView is made up of CALayers: one for each knob etc.

There are value bars that appear when changing parameter values with the knobs that I believe are CALayers, but they do not show up in the CALayer hierarchy. They stay on screen when they should disappear, and end up crashing my app with exit bad access.

How do I gain access to these layers, or why arn't they tied to the rest of the layer hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may not actually be layers, or at least not layers in the current `NSView`. They might be subviews of the NSView, or they might even be NSViews that hover over top of the NSView in question. Almost anything is possible.

The first tool you want is Accessibility Inspector (in /Developer). It lets you point at anything on the screen and find out where it is in the accessibility hierarchy, which very often is closely related to where it is in the view hierarchy. Once you understand where they are in the view hierarchy, you can start digging around with the debugger trying to understand where they are in the layer hierarchy, if they're in the layer hierarchy. Remember that on Mac, `CALayer` is an optional addition to `NSView`. So there might not be layers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Accessibility Inspector is a great help. I hadn't used it before.

Comment: They turned out to be child Windows of the window that owned the audio unit view. So your totally right Rob.

Comment: @Rob Napier… can it be that AXInspector simply *doesn't blink, stir, rustle, etc* if you're over, underneath, or in the midst of a CALayer?  Thats how it seems at first glance when I just now tried it.. but that seems... sort of.. unimaginable! (the bad kind)

Comment: AXInspector tells you what accessibility object you are pointing at. If there is no accessibility object, then it won't respond. NSViews have default accessibility objects, so you can find them. CALayers live within NSViews. They won't have their own accessibility objects. What kind of view are you looking at that doesn't give any response at all?